# Allow only allowed referers in nginx and log blocked

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

Don't beat hard, didn't find in google.

I need to allow only allowed referers domains and empty referers to my site.
block other and log it.
It can be up to 20 referers, so I need kinda array for it.
nginx 1.10.0 standard, ubuntu 16.04

I've tried to make a map but it doesn't work.
1. Don't block.
2. Don't allow me to log in the if {} context

```
  log_format myref '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

  map $http_referer $allow_referer {
            default                  0;
            "~medirl.net"       1;
            "~facebook.com"       1;
            "~clickear.com"       1;
        }

server {
        listen *:80;

        if ($allow_referer = false) {
                return 444;
               access_log /var/log/domain.com/accessBADREF.log myref;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first: you should use [Nginx Referer Module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html) for that.
And in your case you could:

1. Move access_log outside `if ()` with `if=$disallow_referer` parameter
2. Use map name `disallow_referer`
3. Map `default` to `1` and allowed refers to `""`
4. Use `if ($disallow_referer) {` condition

In more details:

```
map $http_referer $allow_referer {
        default                  0;
        "~medirl.net"       1;
        "~facebook.com"      1;
        "~clickear.com"       1;
    }
map $allow_referer $disallow_referer {
    0       1;
    1       "";
}

server {
   listen 127.0.0.1:9999 default_server;

   root /st/hosting/demo/htdocs;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/access_default.log combined if=$allow_referer;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/accessBADREF.log myref if=$disallow_referer;
   if ($disallow_referer) { return 444; }

    # Usage of Nginx Referer Module:
    # valid_referers *medirl.net *facebook.com *clickear.com;
    # if ($invalid_referer) { return 403; }
}

user@server> sudo nginx -t && sudo pkill -HUP nginx
user@server> curl -s -v -e "http://aaa.com" http://127.0.0.1:9999/1.txt 2>&1 | tail -n2
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact

user@server> curl -s -e "http://facebook.com" http://127.0.0.1:9999/1.txt                    
He has been known by many names;  the Prince of Lies, the Director, Lucifer,
Belial, and once, at a party, some obnoxious drunk kept calling him "Dude".
            -- Stig's Inferno
```